# Use Update_all with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, update-all

I'm trying to update all the elements of an Array, but I've this error

> undefined method `update_all' for ...

```
@group.questions.where(user_id: current_user.id).last(@post.question_counter).update_all(post_id: @post.id)
```

While when I try to update_all without condition like :

```
@group.questions.update_all(post_id: @post.id)
```

The method is working. Do you have a solution to run this method ? I could do something like this to solve it, but i think is not really elegant & performant

```
@questions = @group.questions.where(user_id: current_user.id).last(@post.question_counter)
@questions.each do |question|
  question.update(post_id: @post.id)
end
```

Comment: `where(...).last(n)` returns an `Array`, whereas `where(...).limit(n)` returns an `ActiveRecord::Collection`. That's why your code fails, and the answer below works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like

```
@group.questions.where(user_id: current_user.id).
    order('questions.id DESC').limit(@post.question_counter).
    update_all(post_id: @post.id)
```

Comment: Cool exactly what I'm looking for, thanks @Ursul !! So I guess the method .last or .reverse is not working for update_all

Comment: Something like that. It's a method that exit from the "sql mode" let's say :)

Comment: hey @stigGaret one thing to note when using update_all that it doesn't update the updated_at attribute incase you didn't know. (I know this is irrelevant but I found this while trying to solve your problem so I thought you should know ;D)

Comment: Because last returns an Array, not an ActiveRecord::Relation